# Forge is normalising obj file's coordinates

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using forge to view obj file, but it is normalising the obj file's coordinates w.r.t centre of the screen. Due to which at a later point in time when I am rendering the custom THREE.js objects at original coordinate they are very very far apart from the model.

I am seeking one of the two solutions

1. Either I get a forge api to transform the custom object's coordinates the same way forge did for initial model, or
2. Forge displays the model in the correct position without normalising the coordinates but focuses camera to the model on initial load of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Forge typically moves 3D designs to the origin (to avoid floating point precision issues) but it stores the original offset in the `globalOffset` property in the model metadata. You could either:

- Take the `globalOffset` value into account when inserting the custom three.js objects, or
- Load the model with `globalOffset` set to an empty vector (`new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`), as explained in https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher.